# how to convert an Excel file to SQL insert statements

Tags: php, sql, excel

I am stuck in converting an Excel file to a PHP array. I need to insert the data to a table in a SQL database.

Comment: you should found something in google and then post your code in your question .

Comment: My google search on "php read excel" yielded lots of promising links.  Also, if php can play with java objects, check out the Apache POI.  By the way, the downvote is for lack of effort in solving the problem on your own.

Comment: nitpicking, but this is not a question

Comment: i dont no how to play with excel files and how to convert it to manipulate the contents of it. am not talking about csv

Comment: You want to insert your data from excel to mysql table,is it your question?

Comment: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lYlhGyAsnbM   see this video it may help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do that is to convert the excel file to a format that's easy to read, like a CSV file. To do so, open your file in excel and export it to a CSV file.

After that, you will be able to read it in PHP using `fopen()` and [`fgetcsv()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) to insert them using regular SQL access commands.

*Extras:*

As CSV files are like this,

```
"Text field",12,45,87.32,"Another text field"
"I am another row",43,12,98.2,"And another text field"
```

if you are **sure your data is safe from any potential injection attempt** you can use basic string operations to generate SQL statements as well with plain old `fread()`:

```
$sql = 'INSERT INTO `MyTable` VALUES('.$fileRow.')';
```

Which will make something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `MyTable` VALUES("Text field",12,45,87.32,"Another text field")
INSERT INTO `MyTable` VALUES("I am another row",43,12,98.2,"And another text field")
```

Example (untested) script:

```
$file = fopen('data.csv', 'r');

while( ($line = fread($file)) !== false ) {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO `MyTable` VALUES('.$line.')';
    // Do something here, like a PDO query or whatever you use
}
```